# how to handle exceptions inside a class method?

Tags: python, oop, exception, try-catch

I am trying to handle an exception inside a class method, the idea is that if the exception is met then the method has to do some stuff and pass to another value.

Here's what I got so far:

```
class test_class():
    
      def just_a_function(self, value):
          if value is None:
              print('No value')
              raise TypeError('No value')
          else:
              print(value)
              
      def applying_function(self, value):
          # doing some stuff like print('something')

          try:
            self.just_a_function(value)

          except TypeError('No value'):
           # do some other stuff like print('other options')
            pass
```

When applied:

```
# applying #
values=[1,None,3]      
  
if __name__=="__main__":
    
     just_a_class = test_class()
     for value in values:
         just_a_class.applying_function(value)
```

The next error arises:

> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Is there any way to transform `applying_function()` in a form that if `None` then just ignore the value and continue, in a way that expected output could look like this:

```
#1
#No value
#3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an instantiated error in your try except. Instead you should have:

```py
try:
   self.just_a_function(value)
except TypeError as e:
   pass
```

`except` expects a type and not an instantiated object.